# Top tags are different between mobile app and site

Tags: bug, tags, ios-app, tag-score

I was looking at my profile on the iOS mobile app for Arqade, and I noticed that my top tag showed a score of 110.

[image: Top Tags view in moble]

However, I went and checked my profile on the site using my desktop, and it shows that my top tag is only 89.

[image: Top tags on desktop]

My only conclusion is that the mobile app is bugged and includes my upvotes from questions with that tag as well, as I have 21 upvotes in total over my questions with that tag.

Comment: Don't forget to post this in Meta.SE as well

Comment: Yes, it is caused by the upvotes on questions. I have found this to happen too.

Comment: Not a bug, as balpha explains in the dupe, the app simply shows a different thing. (This is the case with both iOS and the android app.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard well that isn't confusing at all.

Comment: Agreed, feel free to suggest something else, but keep in mind what balpha said, that on mobile device there's no way to have tooltips.

Comment: @ShadowWizard where would i suggest this? the comments seem to all say that it is confusing on baplha's answer? should I make a new question here, or edit this into a question saying that we should have consistency

Comment: Well, this one here already got upvotes so it's not "fair" to radically change it. Better start a new question tagged [tag:feature-request] and explain what you have in mind, and why you want it. Also make sure to mention it's asking to change the current behavior, so that it won't get closed as duplicate as well.